# detecting page close (or unload) in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, httprequest

I am building a MVC3 app and on few pages I need to perform few action when the user navigates away from the page.

For example if the user is on page X and clicks any other link I need to perform actions A,B,C

The implementation I have so far uses filters and detects if the user navigates to any other page from page X.

This works except if the user open the link on page X in anther tab. i.e the page X is still open but the user has navigated to another page and actions A, B, C and performed. This not suppose to happen since page X is still open.

I was wondering if there is way to detect page close even on page X so I only perform the action when the page is closed or unloaded ?

Comment: Why not just track in session which pages are open?

Comment: Hmm... but the i still have the problem of detecting when the page is closed. That is my main problem i am not quite sure of how to detect page close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.unload` functionality paired with an ajax post to accomplish this from the front end.

```
$(window).unload(function() {
 //ajax post to controller action
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Controller/Action',
        data : { param1 : "value1", param2: "value2" },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: //do what needs to be done here, alert?
    });
});
```